# Playing a Live Stream with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer, m3u8, m3u

I was trying to play a live stream with AVPlayer. And I somewhat succeeded. My question is, if I play an URL that ends with `m3u8` I can, however, when I try a link that doesn't **(see example below)** I can't! Same behavior when I try to open them with Safari, but on VLC, they both work. Why is that? Unsupported codec?

**Examples:**

- **This works:** https://fluxustv.blogspot.com@bit.ly/fluxusfish?.m3u8
- **This doesn't:** http://www.tvworldfree.ga:3000/p002/p158156/2219

Comment: Do you have those links backwards?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry and thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 0):

The link without “m3u8” is a raw transport stream. AVPlayer does not support that format without a manifest.